# Default workflow not inherited by the child items in Sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a base template in Sitecore. I have assigned Default workflow in the standard fields of this template. Now if we create content item with the templates (Inherited from base template), the default workflow is showing blank.

Is that the expected behavior ? Do I have to set default workflow in standard values for each template ?

Comment: No, it's not. What's your Siteore version?

Comment: Sitecore version is 8.1